# Finding the interest rate of a loan with expected balance after certain period

Tags: compound-interest

I have created a table of repayment schedule of a loan amount \$20,000 at 12% annual interest rate and a repayment of \$500 each month using Excel. The balance, using the first month as an example, is calculated as:

```
($20,000 - $500)*(1+12%/12)=$19,695.
```

| Month | Payment | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 19,695.00 |
| 2 | 500 | 19,386.95 |
| 3 | 500 | 19,075.82 |
| 4 | 500 | 18,761.58 |
| 5 | 500 | 18,444.19 |
| 6 | 500 | 18,123.64 |
| 7 | 500 | 17,799.87 |
| 8 | 500 | 17,472.87 |
| 9 | 500 | 17,142.60 |
| 10 | 500 | 16,809.03 |
| 11 | 500 | 16,472.12 |
| 12 | 500 | 16,131.84 |
| 13 | 500 | 15,788.15 |
| 14 | 500 | 15,441.04 |
| 15 | 500 | 15,090.45 |
| 16 | 500 | 14,736.35 |
| 17 | 500 | 14,378.71 |
| 18 | 500 | 14,017.50 |
| 19 | 500 | 13,652.68 |
| 20 | 500 | 13,284.20 |
| 21 | 500 | 12,912.05 |
| 22 | 500 | 12,536.17 |
| 23 | 500 | 12,156.53 |
| 24 | 500 | 11,773.09 |

Although I can always update the table in Excel, but I wonder if there are formulas to quickly find out:

1. Given load amount \$20,000, monthly repayment \$500 and the remaining balance \$11,773.09 after the 24th repayment, can you find out the annual interest rate?
2. Given load amount \$20,000, annual interest rate 12% and the remaining balance \$11,773.09 after the 24th repayment, can you find out the monthly repayment amount?

---

Edited:
I can answer 2. myself:

```
Monthly repayment amount = ($20,000*(1+12%/12)^24-$11,773.09)*(12%/12)/(1+12%/12)/((1+12%/12)^24-1)
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: (see https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/College_of_the_Canyons/Math_100%3A_Liberal_Arts_Mathematics_(Saburo_Matsumoto)/03%3A_Mathematics_and_Finance/3.02%3A_Annuities_and_Loans)
The balance after $N$ years is
$$
P_N = \frac{d \left(
\left( 1+ \frac{r}{k} \right)^{Nk} - 1
\right)}{
\left( \frac{r}{k} \right)
}
$$
and if you want to calculate the interest rate, you would have to solve for $r$. This can be done iteratively/numerically, but I don't think that you can reverse the formula.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks, but the one you quoted is about interest accumulated, while my question is about loan repayment, your information doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user1589188 -- BTW, what you show below _"I can answer 2. myself"_ is the result if computed at the BEGIN of the period. Pls confirm.

Comment: @m-stgt yes I can confirm my formula is correct (it computes to $500) and is the answer I seek. I can't confirm what you mean though.

Comment: @user1589188 -- Payments can be made either at the **beginning**
of a compounding period (payments in advance, or annuities due) or **at the end** of the period (payments in arrears, or ordinary annuities). Now please confirm the formula you show is for the payment mode BEGIN.

Comment: @m-stgt Ah ok. In that sense then yes, its before.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind if I answer indirecly instead of just presenting a result.
For machines running under Windows (what includes VM thereof), there is an ["emulator" of the HP12C](https://www.educalc.net/page/2338917/) for download, the corresponding manual you may find [here](https://literature.hpcalc.org/#model:12C/source:Official%20HP) (Appendix D, *Formulas Used*, shows all used formulas). This *virtual calculator* offers an acknowledged standard of TVM (time-value of money) what enables you to answer your question in quite short time on your own. HTH

Comment: Thanks. Good to know there is some calculator exists to help getting the value. But I am after a formula so that I can use it in programming to compute the answer directly.

Comment: @user1589188 -- You'll find all formulas in _Appendix D_ of the a. m. manual.